# Negation of a regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I apologize, there are some quite similar questions. I went through them, but couldn't cope, though. It would be nice, if someone could help me on this.

I am willing to find any character (and blanks) *except*:

1. 8-digit long substrings (eg 20110101)
2. substrings such as `0.68G` or `10.76B`(1 or 2 digits, dot, 2 digits, 1 letter)

from the text:

```
b'STN--- WBAN YEARMODA TEMP DEWP SLP STP VISIB WDSP MXSPD GUST MAX MIN
PRCP SNDP FRSHTT\n486200 99999 20110101 79.3 24 74.5 24 1007.2 8
1006.2 8 6.6 24 2.2 24 7.0 999.9 87.8 74.1 0.00G 999.9 010000\n486200 99999 20110102 79.7 24 74.9 24 1007.8 8 1006.9 8 6.1 24 2.8 24 8.0
15.0 91.9 74.8 0.00G 999.9 010010\n486200 99999 20110103 77.5 24 73.6 24 1008.5 8 1007.6 8 6.0 24 2.8 24 6.0 999.9 83.7 73.4* 0.68G 999.9
010000\n486200 99999 20110104 81.2 24 75.0 24 1007.7 8 1006.8 8 6.3 24
3.0 24 5.1 999.9 89.6* 73.0 0.14G 999.9 010010\n486200 99999 20110105 79.7 24 74.8 24 1007.8 8 1006.8 8 7.0 24 2.4 24 6.0 999.9 87.8 73.0 0.57G 999.9 010000\n486200 99999 20110106 77.4 24 74.6 24 1008.8 8 1007.9 8 6.0 24 1.5 24 4.1 999.9 81.0 73.2 0.16G 999.9 010000\n486200 99999 20110107 77.7 24 75.0 24 1008.9
```

I came out with the regex: `(\d{8}|\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}[ABCDEFG])` which finds all (1) and (2).

It now need to 'negate' this. I tried out several possibilities such as `(?! ... )`, but that doesn't seem to work.

My expected output is: `20110101 0.00G 20110102 0.00G 20110103 0.68G 20110104 89.6* 20110105 0.57G 20110106 0.16G20110107`

Do you have suggestions, please?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: is \n present in your text is an actual newline character?

Comment: These looks like space delimited values (with a header row). What are you really trying to do? I guess you're trying extract some columns (and leave others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to negate the pattern. Use the sme regex in `re.findall` function and join the resultant list items with  a space character.

```
>>> s = '''STN--- WBAN YEARMODA TEMP DEWP SLP STP VISIB WDSP MXSPD GUST MAX MIN
PRCP SNDP FRSHTT\n486200 99999 20110101 79.3 24 74.5 24 1007.2 8
1006.2 8 6.6 24 2.2 24 7.0 999.9 87.8 74.1 0.00G 999.9 010000\n486200 99999 20110102 79.7 24 74.9 24 1007.8 8 1006.9 8 6.1 24 2.8 24 8.0
15.0 91.9 74.8 0.00G 999.9 010010\n486200 99999 20110103 77.5 24 73.6 24 1008.5 8 1007.6 8 6.0 24 2.8 24 6.0 999.9 83.7 73.4* 0.68G 999.9
010000\n486200 99999 20110104 81.2 24 75.0 24 1007.7 8 1006.8 8 6.3 24
3.0 24 5.1 999.9 89.6* 73.0 0.14G 999.9 010010\n486200 99999 20110105 79.7 24 74.8 24 1007.8 8 1006.8 8 7.0 24 2.4 24 6.0 999.9 87.8 73.0 0.57G 999.9 010000\n486200 99999 20110106 77.4 24 74.6 24 1008.8 8 1007.9 8 6.0 24 1.5 24 4.1 999.9 81.0 73.2 0.16G 999.9 010000\n486200 99999 20110107 77.7 24 75.0 24 1008.9'''
>>> ' '.join(re.findall(r'(\b\d{8}\b|\b\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}[ABCDEFG])', s))
'20110101 0.00G 20110102 0.00G 20110103 0.68G 20110104 0.14G 20110105 0.57G 20110106 0.16G 20110107'
```

Comment: yes! it is what i just found out. sorry for disturbing. and thx for your reply

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)|\d{1,2}\.\d{2}[a-zA-Z]
```

Just use this with `re.findall`..See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/27

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)|\d{1,2}\.\d{2}[a-zA-Z]', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = "b'STN--- WBAN YEARMODA TEMP DEWP SLP STP VISIB WDSP MXSPD GUST MAX MIN PRCP SNDP FRSHTT\n486200 99999 20110101 79.3 24 74.5 24 1007.2 8 1006.2 8 6.6 24 2.2 24 7.0 999.9 87.8 74.1 0.00G 999.9 010000\n486200 99999 20110102 79.7 24 74.9 24 1007.8 8 1006.9 8 6.1 24 2.8 24 8.0 15.0 91.9 74.8 0.00G 999.9 010010\n486200 99999 20110103 77.5 24 73.6 24 1008.5 8 1007.6 8 6.0 24 2.8 24 6.0 999.9 83.7 73.4* 0.68G 999.9 010000\n486200 99999 20110104 81.2 24 75.0 24 1007.7 8 1006.8 8 6.3 24 3.0 24 5.1 999.9 89.6* 73.0 0.14G 999.9 010010\n486200 99999 20110105 79.7 24 74.8 24 1007.8 8 1006.8 8 7.0 24 2.4 24 6.0 999.9 87.8 73.0 0.57G 999.9 010000\n486200 99999 20110106 77.4 24 74.6 24 1008.8 8 1007.9 8 6.0 24 1.5 24 4.1 999.9 81.0 73.2 0.16G 999.9 010000\n486200 99999 20110107 77.7 24 75.0 24 1008.9\n"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```